# Filtering query with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I just want to ask on how to filter my query with a pivot table. This is how my tables are

**users**(id,name)

**companies**(id,name)

**users_companies**(id,user_id,company_id)

I really want to know how can i filter my list using drop down with pivot table
Then this is how it goes to my EloquentUser

```
   public function paginate($perPage, $search = null, $status = null, $emp_status = null, $level = null, $age = null, $gender = null, $civil_status = null, $role_id = null, $birthmonth = null, $company = null)
    {
    $query = User::query();

    if($company && $company != "" && $company != "All" ) {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($company) {
                $q->where('id', '=', $company);
            });
        }
```

This is for my list.blade or where my dropdown is located

```
<div class="form-group-sm"> 
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="company" name="company">
                    <option selected  disabled>Company</option>
                    @foreach ($companies as $company)
                        @if (($company->id)=="1")
                        <option>All</option>
                        @else
                        <option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

Thank you so much experts!!!

Comment: your question is not clear, can you explain more? what you are going to do. and what results you want?

Comment: I wanted to filter the query but then the filter is based on the "users" table, i wanted to filter the users who have the same company(company is other table) the relationship of company and user is many to many @Qazi

Comment: you are adding all conditions only on User Model, can you share the User and Company relationship methods?

Comment: where can i see that? Sorry im just really a beginner @Qazi

Comment: read this link
`https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many`

Comment: This is their relationship


    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vanguard\Models\Companies', 'users_companies','user_id','company_id');
    } 

@Qazi

Comment: can you tell me what you want to filter, and how you want to filter?

Comment: I want to filter the users that has a relationship to the company table. Filter users depends on the company dropdown.@Qazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get users by using `whereHas` method, here is the example

```
$selected_company_id = $company; //this is form input, company which you selected

$users = User::whereHas('companies', function ($query) use($selected_company_id) {
    $query->where('company_id', $selected_company_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: What does request does? Its because it says that "request" is undefined variable

Comment: @gwapo I update my answer, have a look. also you can use your `$company` variable instead `$selected_company_id` variable

Comment: Thanks @Qazi for the help. I also post my answer below. Have a look at it

Comment: @gwapo How Amazing... Does my answer was not correct??

Comment: it is but there are some tat needed to be edit in your answer. But thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried and it worked

```
$query = User::whereHas('benefits', function ($q) use($benefit) {
            $q->where('benefit_id','=', $benefit);
        });
```